# How to throw InputMismatchException if the next token doesn't match any of the specified strings?

Tags: java, exception

I know that `Scanner.next("A")` will return string "A" if the next token matches "A", otherwise it will throw and `InputMismatchException`. But my code needs to be in a way such that it would throw `InputMismatchException` if it couldn't find any match from a group of Strings. For example, I want `InputMismatchException` to be thrown if neither "A" nor "B" nor "C" is the next token.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Scanner.next(Pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) with a regexp pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABC]");
myScanner.next(pattern);
```

Or even

```
myScanner.next("[ABC]");
```

Because, according to the Javadoc, [Scanner.next(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29)

> An invocation of this method of the form next(pattern) behaves in
>   exactly the same way as the invocation next(Pattern.compile(pattern)).

You don't even have to worry that the version with `next(String)` will build a Pattern object every time because the implementation maintains a cache of Pattern objects.

**Edit:** If the strings that you want to match are not single characters, the regular expression pattern would just be different:

```
myScanner.next("(AB|CD|EF)"); // throws for everything except AB, CD and EF.
```

Comment: But that wouldn't work if the strings I'm looking for have more than one character. For example what if I want to see whether the next token matches "AB" or "CD" or "EF".

Comment: It's a regular expression, you can do a lot of things (though not everything). If the patterns are AB, CD and EF you would use `next("(AB|CD|EF));"`.